# Adding a subpath to the React website for the Hash Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

We are using a react website with hash-router and the local URL looks something like this:

```
http://0.0.0.0:4321/#/
```

I want to always add a subpath for the URL and it should work something like this:

```
http://0.0.0.0:4321/somepath/#/
http://0.0.0.0:4321/somepath/#/somepage
```

I always want to have the URL in above format. While I have used base path in Hashrouter like this:

```
<HashRouter basename={'/somepath'}>
```

I am getting a URL in this format:

```
http://0.0.0.0:4321/#/somepath/
http://0.0.0.0:4321/#/somepath/somepage
```

Any changes that I have to do else where in the project to always have this path?
I have tried to replicate this in a Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-jk8e9?file=/src/App.tsx, but it seems to not work properly.